# Soundcloud Widget API - seekTo does not work with paused audio

Tags: soundcloud

I want to share a podcast using SoundCloud and I've created some links to help the listeners scrub the audio. Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="SC.Widget('player').seekTo(10000);">GO TO 10s</a> - 
<a href="#" onclick="SC.Widget('player').seekTo(30000);">GO TO 30s</a>
```

So when the user clicks on "GO TO 10s", the audio has to go to 10 seconds. However it works only after the user press the play button.
Is there any way to start the audio AND move the audio to the right time when user click on "GO TO" link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar letting the user click on a waveform...

_getScWidget() is a function that returns the soundcloud widget

code snippet

```
  this.getWaveformClick = function() {
    try {

      ...
      // target is calculated position in ms based on where on the waveform the user clicks
      this._getScWidget().isPaused(function isPaused(p) {
        if (p == true) {
          // if paused play then seek
          self._getScWidget().play();
          self._getScWidget().seekTo(target);
        } else {
          // if not paused, just seek
          self._getScWidget().seekTo(target);
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // error handler
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my issue inspired by @SteveE answer. Here is the code:

```
var player = SC.Widget('player');
var miliseconds = -1;

player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
    if (miliseconds >= 0) {
        player.seekTo(miliseconds);
    }
});

seekTo = function(minutes, seconds) {
    miliseconds = ((minutes * 60) + seconds) * 1000;

    player.isPaused(function isPaused(p) {
        if (p == true) {
            player.play();
        } else {
            player.seekTo(miliseconds);
        }
    });
}
```